# Mobile web app capability and viewport in safari mobile 13

Tags: html, ios, mobile-safari, meta, ios13

For a webapp, I tried two cool meta tags, namely **apple-mobile-web-app-capable** and **viewport**. The first one to allow the web application to be displayed fullscreen in iOS, when the application is added to the desktop, the latter to avoid a user to zoom in the application.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

To my recollection, those two meta were working properly before the update to mobile safari 13. After the update, a web app on the desktop screen shows a status bar, and the user can zoom.

It tried on iPad and iPhone, with the same kind of problems.

Does anybody also experience this kind of problem with the new mobile safari ?
Does anybody has a fix for that ?